# How to dynamically change client_secret in Spring Security with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Now I have this configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          sbbol:
            client-id: zdcffffff
            client-secret: ffffffffff
            scope:
              - openid
            client-authentication-method: post
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            client-authentication-scheme: form
        provider:
          sbbol:
            authorization-uri: ${SBBOL_AUTH_URI}
            token-uri: ${SBBOL_AUTH_URI}
            user-info-uri: ${SBBOL_AUTH_URI}
            user-name-attribute: sub
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable();
        http.cors().disable();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth2/authorization/sbbol", "/login/oauth2/code/sbbol")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.oauth2Login()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user")
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

this works, but my provider asks me to change the client-secret every 30 days via a rest api call. I have a question, how do I set the new client-secret in Spring Security? Maybe I can store the configuration in the database?

Comment: Yes, you need to persists these details in the database. You can use `oauth_client_details` table with following similar type of columns to save the details and later you can change it with using the rest interface.
`client_id, client_secret, scope, authorized_grant_types, web_server_redirect_uri, authorities, access_token_validity, refresh_token_validity, additional_information, autoapprove`

Comment: @harry Is this exactly possible in my case? I think this is only possible with OAuth 2.0 Server. In my case, I am as a client. I am trying to connect to a SSO provider, the same as Google or Okta

Comment: Above case is for when your app is acting as OAuth provider too, running the OAuth server within the same service or separate independent server. As your provider is 3rd party server so in that case as you mentioned they're exposing an endpoint to change it so you need to go with a custom solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created my own implementation for org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository. I can store the settings in the database and change them.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JdbcClientRegistrationRepository implements ClientRegistrationRepository {

    private final SsoProviderConfigurationRepository ssoProviderConfigurationRepository;

    @Override
    public ClientRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
        Assert.hasText(registrationId, "registrationId cannot be empty");
        SsoProviderConfiguration providerConfiguration = ssoProviderConfigurationRepository.findByRegistrationId(registrationId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("ClientRegistration not found by id=" + registrationId));

        String[] scopes = providerConfiguration.getScope().split(",");
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(providerConfiguration.getRegistrationId())
            .clientId(providerConfiguration.getClientId())
            .clientSecret(providerConfiguration.getClientSecret())
            .clientName(providerConfiguration.getClientName())
            .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType(providerConfiguration.getAuthorizationGrantType()))
            .authorizationUri(providerConfiguration.getAuthorizationUri())
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(new ClientAuthenticationMethod(providerConfiguration.getClientAuthenticationMethod()))
            .scope(scopes)
            .tokenUri(providerConfiguration.getTokenUri())
            .userInfoAuthenticationMethod(new AuthenticationMethod(providerConfiguration.getAuthenticationMethod()))
            .userInfoUri(providerConfiguration.getUserInfoUri())
            .userNameAttributeName(providerConfiguration.getUserNameAttributeName())
            .redirectUri(providerConfiguration.getRedirectUri())
            .build();
    }
}
```

My entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sso_provider_configuration")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SsoProviderConfiguration implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String registrationId;

    private String clientId;

    private String clientSecret;

    private String clientAuthenticationMethod;

    private String authorizationGrantType;

    private String redirectUri;

    private String scope;

    private String clientName;

    private String authorizationUri;

    private String tokenUri;

    private String jwkSetUri;

    private String issuerUri;

    private String authenticationMethod;

    private String userNameAttributeName;

    private String UserInfoUri;
}
```

Repository

```
public interface SsoProviderConfigurationRepository extends JpaRepository<SsoProviderConfiguration, Long> {

    Optional<SsoProviderConfiguration> findByRegistrationId(String code);
}
```

Comment: Nice work! In a similar usecase, we could'nt make it work. How do you inject your updated `JdbcClientRegistrationRepository ` into your `WebSecurityConfigAdapter`, in other words how does it get injected at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

i have this that may be work, it's not dynamic but you could work around

```
@Value("${security.oauth.client.id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${security.oauth.client.password}")
private String clientPassword;


@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

    
    
    clients.inMemory()
    .withClient(clientId)
    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
    .secret(clientPassword)
    .resourceIds("resource_id")
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenTimeOut)
    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenTimeOut)
   ;

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this config class:

```
import com.yourmom.security.oauth2.AppleClientSecretGenerator;
import com.yourmom.security.oauth2.ClientSecretGenerator;
import com.yourmom.service.DynamicInMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.ClientsConfiguredCondition;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration(
    proxyBeanMethods = false
)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({OAuth2ClientProperties.class})
@Conditional({ClientsConfiguredCondition.class})
class OAuthProps {
    OAuthProps() {
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamicInMemoryClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations(OAuth2ClientProperties properties,AppleClientSecretGenerator appleClientSecretGenerator) {
       return new DynamicInMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(
           new ArrayList(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(properties).values()),
           new HashMap<String, ClientSecretGenerator>(){{
               put("apple",appleClientSecretGenerator);
           }}
       );
    }
}
```

This interface:

```
public interface ClientSecretGenerator {
    public String generateClientSecret() throws Exception;
}
```

This implementation (if you like, its what I'm using it for)

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.JwsHeader;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.util.Date;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

@Service
public class AppleClientSecretGenerator implements ClientSecretGenerator {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apple.keyId}")
    private String appleKeyId;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apple.teamId}")
    private String appleTeamId;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.apple.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Override
    public String generateClientSecret() throws Exception {
        // Generate a private key for token verification from your end with your creds
        PrivateKey pKey = generatePrivateKey();
        return Jwts.builder()
            .setHeaderParam(JwsHeader.KEY_ID, appleKeyId)
            .setIssuer(appleTeamId)
            .setAudience("https://appleid.apple.com")
            .setSubject(clientId)
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 500)))
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256,pKey)
            .compact();
    }

    private PrivateKey generatePrivateKey() throws Exception {
        // here i have added cert at resource/apple folder. So if you have added somewhere else, just replace it with your path ofcert
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:security/oauth/apple/AuthKey_"+appleKeyId+".p8");
        final PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(file));
        final JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
        final PrivateKeyInfo object = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
        final PrivateKey pKey = converter.getPrivateKey(object);
        pemParser.close();
        return pKey;
    }
}
```

And then finally this `ClientRegistrationRepository`:

```
import com.yourmom.security.oauth2.ClientSecretGenerator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

public class DynamicInMemoryClientRegistrationRepository implements ClientRegistrationRepository, Iterable<ClientRegistration> {
    private final Map<String, ClientRegistration> registrations;
    private final Map<String, ClientSecretGenerator> clientSecretGeneratorMap;


    public DynamicInMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(List<ClientRegistration> clientRegistrations,Map<String, ClientSecretGenerator> clientSecretGeneratorMap) {
        this.clientSecretGeneratorMap = clientSecretGeneratorMap;
        registrations = createRegistrationsMap(clientRegistrations);
    }

    private static Map<String, ClientRegistration> createRegistrationsMap(List<ClientRegistration> registrations) {
        Assert.notEmpty(registrations, "registrations cannot be empty");
        return toUnmodifiableConcurrentMap(registrations);
    }

    private static Map<String, ClientRegistration> toUnmodifiableConcurrentMap(List<ClientRegistration> registrations) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, ClientRegistration> result = new ConcurrentHashMap();
        Iterator var2 = registrations.iterator();

        while(var2.hasNext()) {
            ClientRegistration registration = (ClientRegistration)var2.next();
            Assert.state(!result.containsKey(registration.getRegistrationId()), () -> {
                return String.format("Duplicate key %s", registration.getRegistrationId());
            });
            result.put(registration.getRegistrationId(), registration);
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }


    public ClientRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
        Assert.hasText(registrationId, "registrationId cannot be empty");

        ClientRegistration immutableClientRegistration = this.registrations.get(registrationId);

        try {
            return ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId(registrationId)
                .clientId(immutableClientRegistration.getClientId())
                .authorizationGrantType(immutableClientRegistration.getAuthorizationGrantType())
                .clientName(immutableClientRegistration.getClientName())
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(immutableClientRegistration.getClientAuthenticationMethod())
                .clientSecret(clientSecretGeneratorMap.get(registrationId) != null ?  clientSecretGeneratorMap.get(registrationId).generateClientSecret() : immutableClientRegistration.getClientSecret())
                .redirectUri(immutableClientRegistration.getRedirectUri())
                .scope(immutableClientRegistration.getScopes())
                .providerConfigurationMetadata(immutableClientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getConfigurationMetadata())
                .issuerUri(immutableClientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getIssuerUri())
                .jwkSetUri(immutableClientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getJwkSetUri())
                .tokenUri(immutableClientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getTokenUri())
                .authorizationUri(immutableClientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getAuthorizationUri())
                                .userInfoUri(immutableClientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri())
                .userInfoAuthenticationMethod(immutableClientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getAuthenticationMethod())
                .userNameAttributeName(immutableClientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUserNameAttributeName())
                .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed while generating client secret: " + e,e);
        }

    }

    public Iterator<ClientRegistration> iterator() {
        return this.registrations.values().iterator();
    }
}
```